# How to use HuggingFace models for chatbot-like answers

Tags: chatbot, huggingface-transformers

I have a very basic question:

I would like to download a model like Vicuna from HuggingFace and use it to ask arbitrary questions, like "What topics are discussed in this text?" or "Summarize what happened in this text." If I try this in the [GUI](https://chat.lmsys.org/) I get reasonable answers to all of my questions. But, when I try the same thing using HuggingFace versions, the quality is much worse. Rather than respond to the questions as I would expect, it typically just outputs the input text and some additional generated text, which is not what I'm after.

I think I am likely selecting the wrong model type. So far I have tried `AutoModelForCausalLM` based on the HuggingFace docs, and also `AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM`. I'm using the `LlamaTokenizer` tokenizer, and have also tried the `AutoTokenizer`. I feel like I must be missing something...

Here is some example code:

```
from transformers import LlamaTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM
tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained("lmsys/vicuna-7b-v1.3", legacy=False)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("lmsys/vicuna-7b-v1.3")

input_text = """
In one sentence, describe what happened in this video transcript: Hey everyone, hope you're having a nice day. I'm looking forward to playing piano later, but how are you all? Ha ha, that's nice. Ok, let's get started. This is one of my favorite songs. Oh yeah that sounds fun.
"""

input_ids = tokenizer(input_text, return_tensors="pt")
out = model.generate(input_ids['input_ids'], max_new_tokens=100)
result = tokenizer.decode(out[0])

print(result)
"<s> In one sentence, describe what happened in this video transcript: Hey everyone, hope you're having a nice day. I'm looking forward to playing piano later, but how are you all? Ha ha, that's nice. Ok, let's get started. This is one of my favorite songs. Oh yeah that sounds fun. I'm gonna play it now. Wow, that was really good. I'm so happy. I love playing music. I'm so glad I have this channel. I'm so grateful for all of you. I'm so happy to be alive. I love you all.</s>"
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction/offer advice I would be super grateful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would recommend is altering your prompting, many models based on Llama are fine tuned with a specific prompt format and you will get the best performance if you stick with that. When using a GUI like the one linked above that formatting is typically hidden from the user.

I dont see a prompt template for the exact model you are using but there is a prompt template provided here: https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/vicuna-7B-v1.3-GGML

```
A chat between a curious user and an artificial intelligence assistant. The assistant gives helpful, detailed, and polite answers to the user's questions.

USER: prompt
ASSISTANT:
```

I would also recommend using [Pipelines](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/main_classes/pipelines#transformers.Conversation) from huggingface (in this case you likely want `ConversationalPipeline`) and/or a package like [LangChain](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/providers/huggingface#llm) for building a chat application.

As far as model selection goes `AutoModelForCausalLM` is the right choice for a decoder model that you will use for text generation and since your model is based on llama the from_pretrained method of `AutoTokenizer` will return a `LlamaTokenizer`. `AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM` is typically used for encoder decoder models where you want an lm head for text generation. Hope this helps!

Edit:

I ran your same code snippet above but replacing `input_text` with

```
input_text = """
A chat between a curious user and an artificial intelligence assistant. The assistant gives helpful, detailed, and polite answers to the user's questions.

USER: In one sentence, describe what happened in this video transcript: Hey everyone, hope you're having a nice day. I'm looking forward to playing piano later, but how are you all? Ha ha, that's nice. Ok, let's get started. This is one of my favorite songs. Oh yeah that sounds fun.
ASSISTANT:
"""
```

here is the response I got:

```
ASSISTANT:

In this video transcript, the speaker expresses their excitement to play piano and shares their favorite song with the audience.
```

Comment: Strangely, I still get the same kind of result I was before when using the prompt you suggested (the response is just a continuation of the original script vs. an answer). This does not happen when I download the weights via FastChat and run the model locally, it's only an issue when using the HuggingFace implementations... I wonder if there's some hyperparameter I'm missing...

Comment: Hey! On my end I can duplicate the unwanted behavior you're getting with the original prompt but it switches to answering correctly with the formatted one above. I dont know about hyperparameters as I've copied your code snippet and just changed the input text. What version of `transformers` are you using? Im on 4.31.0